# Form sending multiple times

Tags: jquery

So, I have following script to handle form submission:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >    
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('body').on('click', '.rh_contact_seller_submit', function() {

    if($('#rhc_email').val() === '') {
        mu_form_validate($('#rhc_email'));
     } else {
        var data = {
            'action': 'mu_send_message',
            'email': $('#rhc_email').val(),
            'phone': $('#rhc_phone').val(),                             
            'message': $('#rhc_ask').val(),             
            'to_author': $('#rhc_author').val()
        };

        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if(response === 'success'){
                alert('Message Sent Successfully!');
                $('.rhpm_close').click();
            }
        });
    } 
});
});
</script>
```

However, it often sends requests multiple times.

Is there a way for me to only send it once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '.rh_contact_seller_submit', function() {
```

To

```
$('.rh_contact_seller_submit').on('click', function() {
```

This will work.!

Comment: In addition, if you only want an event to fire once, use `one` http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @LeeTaylor That's great.! I haven't heard about `one`